# create a pivot or matrix dataframe with values representing sum of respective combinations

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matrix, pivot

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
Strike  Right  Price
4000    CE     45
4000    PE     55
4100    CE     30
4100    PE     60
```

I want to create a df such that the output is

```
       4000PE  4100PE
4000CE  100     105
4100CE   85     90
```

Can you guide me in the direction how i can create this
Is np.add.outer faster ? or is it numpy's broadcasting that is faster ?

Comment: Numpy broadcasting is most likely the fastest

Comment: You might want to explain how your logic generalizes, can you have more than 2 categories?

Comment: @mozway : The logic is simply adding  the CE and PE prices for different strikes combination

Comment: OK, that's what I had understood. My question was also if Strike can have more than two values? In this case the output should be a n x n dataframe with n the number of unique Strike values

Answer (score 2):

For an efficient method, you can [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and broadcast only the needed combinations:

```
tmp = df.pivot(index='Strike', columns='Right', values='Price')

out = pd.DataFrame(tmp['CE'].to_numpy()[:,None] + tmp['PE'].to_numpy(),
                   index=tmp.index.astype(str)+'CE',
                   columns=tmp.index.astype(str)+'PE'
                  ).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
```

Output:

```
        4000PE  4100PE
4000CE     100     105
4100CE      85      90
```

Comment: Faster is pivoting + broadcasting like only broadcasting and selecting like my solution generally?

Comment: I always think pivoting is complicated and slow pandas operation.

Comment: @jezrael well, for 4 values it's insignificant any approach will run within a ms, but if you have more combinations broadcasting like you did is O(n²). Computing all combinations to only keep a fraction of it is not efficient.

Comment: yop, agree. It depends if OP need all combinations or only `PE`, `CE` slices.

Comment: @asimo are you talking about my answer or the other one? I provided an output that looks like what you shown, you can also have a MultiIndex if needed. Can you provide a pandas object that reproduces the exact expected output?

Comment: @mozway: I have tried the answers, they work fine. The index missing comment earlier (which i dleted) was an error on my part. sorry about that.
But can you tell me which is faster. I have like 20 by 20 matrix to give estimate of size or the pairs

Comment: @jezrael I have tried the answers, they work fine. The index missing comment earlier (which i dleted) was an error on my part. sorry about that.
But can you tell me which is faster. I have like 20 by 20 matrix to give estimate of size or the pairs

Comment: @asimo do you mean that you have 20 different Strike values and PE/CE? Then I believe my approach is faster since I only compute the needed combinations.

Comment: @asimo - if matrix is 20x20 both solutions are fast in my opinion

Comment: the challenge is..i'll refresh or run this every 1 second..as i refresh values every 1 second

Comment: @asimo - What is size of data?

Comment: I tested with 20 different Strike, my approach is `1.07 ms ± 28 µs`, full broadcasting is `1.26 ms ± 64.5 µs` and this could get worse with greater N. If you run "only" every second, this is not highly significant.

Comment: approx 20 rows and 2 columns, culminating into 20x20

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0fdw.png) is a comparison for a large range of `N`. My approach in blue, the full broadcast + filter in orange.

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy broadcasting:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[['Strike','Right']])

a = df['Price'].to_numpy()

out = pd.DataFrame(a + a[:, None], index=mux, columns=mux)
print (out)
Strike       4000      4100     
Right          CE   PE   CE   PE
Strike Right                    
4000   CE      90  100   75  105
       PE     100  110   85  115
4100   CE      75   85   60   90
       PE     105  115   90  120
```

For select `CE` and `PE` slices use:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
out1 = out.loc[idx[:, 'CE'], idx[:, 'PE']]
out1.index = out1.index.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}{x[1]}')
out1.columns = out1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}{x[1]}')
print (out1)
        4000PE  4100PE
4000CE     100     105
4100CE      85      90
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which requires the data ordered as is in the question:

```
d = df[['Strike', 'Right']].astype(str).sum(axis=1)

m1 = df['Right'].eq('CE')

pd.DataFrame((df['Price'].values + df['Price'].values[:, None])[::2, 1::2], 
             index=d[m1], 
             columns=d[~m1])
```

Output:

```
        4000PE  4100PE
4000CE     100     105
4100CE      85      90
```